# Generating an iOS manifest on the fly

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate an Apple iOS manifest on the fly without having to point at a physically present file. Reason is that the IPA link inside the `manifest.plist` file will contain an URL with a security token in it that expires after a certain period.

Here's the relevant bit of code in the action method that returns a valid manifest file:

```
//manifestTemplate is just a string resource, then I insert the correct value for each XML node...
var output = string.Format(manifestTemplate, buildSASUrl, smallIconUrl, largeIconUrl, bundleId, version, title);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
return new FileContentResult(bytes, "text/xml") { FileDownloadName = "manifest.plist" };
```

And the link I'm trying to have iOS open to install the application is:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://website.net/Manifest/GetIOSManifest?buildId=fjEf1li1MUuxjVboSj7mVA
```

I've also tried to fool iOS by renaming the `GetIOSManifest` action to `manifest.plist` that didn't work either.

Is there any way to achieve this ? I'm doing the tests with Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out by making sure the action method returned a `FileContentResult` with no `FileDownloadName` with mime type `text/xml`

Also, the client side javascript has to `encodeURIComponent()` the manifest's URL which is used in the `itms-services` link.